# Помогите разобраться со vue.js, не срабатывает выделение текста

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите почему не работает выделение. По клику на иконку like стоит обработчик события, который меняет like_status: с false на true. Но, ничего не происходит. При этом если вручную поставить true - все работает. Не могу понять, почему не срабатывает функция.

```js
Vue.component('anegdotes', {
  props: ['data'],
   methods: {},
   template: `
  <ul class="list-jokes__list">
  <li class="list-jokes__list-item">{{ data.joke }}<img class="like" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/thumb-up--v1.png" height="20px" @click="like_active()"></li>
  </ul>
   `, 
});

const vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    joke: '',
    urlAnegdotes: 'https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any?type=single&amount=10',
    anegdotes: [],
     search: '',
     like_status: false,
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(this.urlAnegdotes);
      const content = await response.json();
      const result = content.jokes;
      this.anegdotes.push(...result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
   },
   methods: {
      like_active() {
         if (!this.like_status) {
            this.like_status = this.like_status = 'true';
         }
      }
  },
   computed: {
      searchHandler() {
         return this.anegdotes.filter(elem => {
            return elem.joke.includes(this.search);
         })
      }
  }
});
```

```css
.list-jokes{
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 400px;
   margin: 50px auto;
   background-color: rgb(247, 213, 175);
   word-break: break-word;
   position: relative;
}

.list-jokes__title{
   background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   margin-top: auto;
}

.list-jokes__list{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 0 10px 25px;
}

.list-jokes__list-item{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.input-search{
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 5px;
   outline: none;
}

.button-search{
   background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
   border: none;
   padding: 8px;
   min-width: 100px;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: .4s ease-in;
}

.like{
   cursor: pointer;
}

.like-active {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Anegdotes</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

   <div id='app' class="list-jokes">
      <input class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="search for anecdote" v-model="search"
         @search='searchHandler()'>
      <h3 class="list-jokes__title">List of jokes</h3>

      
      <anegdotes :data="data" v-for="(data, index) in searchHandler" :key="index"
         :class="{ 'like-active' : like_status}" />
   </div>




   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `this.like_status = this.like_status = 'true';` что по вашему мнению, должно произойти тут?

Comment: @bonusrk, это как контрольный выстрел в̶-н̶о̶г̶у̶: 'если одно присваивание не сработает, то второе уж наверняка".

Comment: @Игорь Солодовник а если коротко, то за минусом всего остального, что там не так (а там многое не так), отвечая на сам вопрос - метод `like_active` вне области видимости компонента `anegdodes` (как собственно и `this.like_status`), а зачем-то в родителе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил все самые очевидные ошибки, добавил правильную связь с родительским компонентом (через событие), оставил странный вывод кучи `<ul>` с одним дочерним элементом, стили и грамматика тоже без изменений:

```js
Vue.component('anegdotes', {
  props: ['data'],
  template: `
    <ul class="list-jokes__list">
      <li class="list-jokes__list-item">
        {{ data.joke }}
        <img class="like" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/thumb-up--v1.png" height="20px" @click="$emit('like', data.id)">
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
});

const vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    urlAnegdotes: 'https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any?type=single&amount=10',
    anegdotes: [],
    search: '',
    like_status: {},
  },
  computed: {
    searchResults() {
      return this.anegdotes.filter(elem => elem.joke.includes(this.search)); 
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onLike(id) {
      if (!isFinite(+id)) return;
      this.$set(this.like_status, id, !this.like_status[id]);
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(this.urlAnegdotes).then(r => r.json());
      this.anegdotes = response.jokes.map(({ flags, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.list-jokes {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: rgb(247, 213, 175);
  word-break: break-word;
  position: relative;
}

.list-jokes__title {
  background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.list-jokes__list { margin: 0; padding: 0 0 10px 25px; }
.list-jokes__list-item { margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0 10px 0 10px; }
.input-search { font-size: 16px; padding: 5px; outline: none; }

.button-search {
  background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .4s ease-in;
}

.like { cursor: pointer; }
.like-active { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div id="app" class="list-jokes">
  <input v-model="search" class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="search for anecdote">
  <h3 class="list-jokes__title">List of jokes</h3>
  <anegdotes v-for="item in searchResults" :key="item.id" :data="item" :class="{ 'like-active' : like_status[item.id] }" @like="onLike"></anegdotes>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

К сожалению, здесь в спиппете переносы внутри тегов ломают выполнение, так что атрибуты пришлось записать в одну строку.

Описание каждого из сделанных изменений не прикладываю, т.к. все они исправляют ошибки совершенные из-за нежелания внимательно читать/понимать [оф.документацию Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) (ошибки от недостаточного усвоения теорчасти - не воспроизводятся, поэтому их подробный разбор будет бесполезным для сообщества). Но оставшийся после "чистки" код вполне минимален, и в нем не так трудно разобраться самостоятельно.